# WPF ToolTip Style with dynamic LayoutTransform

Tags: wpf, dynamic, styles, layouttransform

I have an app that scales it's UI and I want to scale the ToolTips with it.
I have tried doing this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" Value="{DynamicResource scaleTransf}"/>
    ...
</Style>
```

...where `scaleTransf` is a resource that I change via code:

```
Application.Current.Resources["scaleTransf"] = new ScaleTransform(...);
```

with:

```
<ScaleTransform x:Key="scaleTransf" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
```

Most of the ToolTips do get scaled in size but some of them that are created by C# code don't get scaled. I've checked and it seems that I don't set their Style or LayoutTransform by code, so I don't really understand what is going wrong... Moreover, I have the impression that the above XAML code worked fine a few days ago. :(

Is there sth I can do to make it work all the time without setting the LayoutTransform in code-behind?

**EDIT :** The ToolTips that don't change scale are the ones that have become visible before.

**EDIT1 :** If I set the `LayoutTransform` of each `ToolTip` instance to `scaleTransf` in code behind using `SetResourceReference()` everything works fine. I don't understand why the Style doesn't work while it is supposed to do exactly the same for every `ToolTip` that gets created... Based on my limited knowledge of WPF I would call this a BUG!

---

**EDIT2 :**

I have also tried this:

```
Application.Current.Resources.Remove("scaleTransf");
Application.Current.Resources.Add("scaleTransf", new ScaleTransform(val, val));
```

---

**EDIT3 :** My attempt to solve this using a DependencyProperty:

In MainWindow.xaml.cs :

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TransformToApplyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TransformToApply", typeof(Transform), typeof(MainWindow));
    public Transform TransformToApply
    {
        get { return (Transform)this.GetValue(TransformToApplyProperty); }
    }
```

Somewhere in MainWindow, in response to a user input:

```
this.SetValue(TransformToApplyProperty, new ScaleTransform(val, val));
```

XAML Style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" Value="{Binding TransformToApply, Source={x:Reference WndXName}}"/>
...
```

Using this code, not a single one of the ToolTips seem to scale accordingly.

Comment: try `Application.Current.Resources.Add(xxx)` instead.

Comment: I've just tried removing and re-adding the resource and it's the same thing.

Comment: what do yoy mean by removing and re-adding? is this dynamic? post the XAML and code.

Comment: See EDIT2 for what I mean.

Comment: That's it's namespace definition: `xmlns:swm="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Media;assembly=PresentationCore"`

Comment: you don't need that. all WPF classes are mapped to the default xml namespace.

Comment: so, when are you changing the resource? I don't think that changing the resource will automatically make everything that uses it re-draw itself

Comment: I have a slider for the user to regulate the scale on demand. Also I have tried putting the code for changing the resource inside a `this.Resources.BeginInit()` - `EndInit()` block but I don't know if that helps at all. What will make everything re-draw itself? Should I use `InvalidateVisual()` or sth similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think a resource is the best approach in your situation.

It would be better in this case to declare your Transform as a DependencyProperty of your window:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TransformToApplyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TransformToApply", typeof(Transform), typeof(Window));
```

then in XAML:

```
<Window  .... (all the xmlns)
         x:Name="window"/>
    <AnyControl ScaleTransform="{Binding TransformToApply, ElementName=window}"/>
</Window>
```

Comment: I have just tried this but with the difference that I've set the Transform in a Style. Setting it for every control is not a very easy thing to do (and I think that my 1st solution would have worked this way too). Assuming that I haven't done anything wrong, it doesn't work. See EDIT3 above.

Comment: Try with `{Binding TransformToApply, Source={x:Reference window}}`

Comment: This gives me an Exception: `Unresolved reference 'MainWindow'.` I've tried adding the namespace for the MainWindow and it still doesn't find it!

Comment: the {x:Reference} should point to the x:Name of the window, not its class, did you do it that way?

Comment: No. I've corrected it now, but again it doesn't work. It still can't find the x:Name given. Note: my Style is in a separate XAML file, not in the MainWindow.xaml (I don't know if that matters and how to correct it without moving it. Again, I've tried using namespaces but with no luck).

Comment: Finally, I decided to use SetResourceReference to set the LayoutTransform of the ToolTips that didn't scale correctly (I didn't change my original code). That solved the problem. I would expect that doing the same via a Style would have the exact same results, but apparently it doesn't. I really don't get it... If someone does, let me know. Thanks.
@HighCore If I don't get any better answer soon I will mark your answer as solution. :)