# Scale tooltip with window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I got some WPF application. I placed content in `viewbox` and it works well, but `tooltip` is not scale with other content. I understand why, but i cant get how to scale it. Should i bind actual size in window to some size in tooltip? Or maybe there is some common practice for tooltip scaling? Thanks.

Comment: Question is not clear, what do you mean by scaling? Did you try increasing the font size of the tool tip?

Comment: @CarbineCoder, i mean when i run my application i can resize my window just by draging its corners - as usual window. And all content placed inside viewbox will scale properly, but not tooltips.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? Sorry still could not understand it. For me I have never scaled tooltip as it contains only text?!

Comment: @CarbineCoder, here http://prntscr.com/4nwtgf grey is tooltip. Why should it contain only text? It can contain any wpf UI elements.

Comment: Check this - [WPF ToolTip Style with dynamic LayoutTransform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764333/wpf-tooltip-style-with-dynamic-layouttransform)

Comment: when you drag a window from the sides or corners the event is re-sizing followed by re-layout on sub controls, this is not equivalent to scaling. Windows 8.1 offers [DPI Scaling Enhancements](http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2013/07/15/windows-8-1-dpi-scaling-enhancements/) but in that case it may not be necessary to handle in code unless you want your application to be dpi-aware.

Comment: Could you please provide some code? And try to ask your question more clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to scale the ToolTip's content by `ScaleTransform` yourself. Note that you have to set `LayoutTransform` (not `RenderTransform`) so that the ToolTip will resize itself to fit its content. The problem is how to know the scaling factor to apply on the ToolTip's content? It's fortunate that we can get that factor easily from the `Viewbox`. Here is an example XAML code for a `Button` inside your Viewbox:

```
<Viewbox Name="vb">
   <Grid>          
      <Button>
          <Button.ToolTip>
             <Border Name="toolTipContent">                    
                <TextBlock>Some instruction...</TextBlock>
             </Border>
          </Button.ToolTip>
          Open
      </Button>          
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

You should re-scale the ToolTip when resizing the window, so we should handle the event `SizeChanged`:

```
ContainerVisual cv;
private void sizeChanged_handler(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e){
   if(cv == null) {            
        cv = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(vb, 0) as ContainerVisual;
   }
   //cv.Transform is in fact a ScaleTransform
   toolTipContent.LayoutTransform = cv.Transform;
}
```